# spring integration ftp inbound adapter in distributed mode

Tags: ftp, spring-integration

I am using `Spring Integration: FTP Inbound Channel Adapter` to read files from remote FTP server. My problem is, will it able to handle around 5 millions files per day?

If I deploy my project war on 2 different servers in an distributed mode, then will it problematic? Because on both the servers `FTP Inbound Channel Adapter` will be running. Then both the adapters will read same file twice.
Please help me setting up this system in distributed mode.

**EDIT:**
I have set up my `Spring Integration` project war on 2 servers. It is using `FTP Inbound Channel Adapter`. Both servers' adapter `remote-location` is pointing to same ftp file location. When I start both the servers, then both the servers starts transferring same files and generates messages multiple times. I am using `Redis MetaData Store` as per `Gary's` suggestion.
My `Ftp Inbound Channel Adapter` on both the servers looks like this:

```
<bean id="redisMessageStore" class="org.springframework.integration.redis.store.RedisMessageStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="redisConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean name="metadataStore" class="org.springframework.integration.redis.metadata.RedisMetadataStore">
    <constructor-arg name="connectionFactory" ref="redisConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="fileSystemPersistantFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter"> 
    <constructor-arg name="store" ref="metadataStore"/> <constructor-arg name="prefix" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="ftpPersistantFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.filters.FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter"> 
    <constructor-arg name="store" ref="metadataStore"/> <constructor-arg name="prefix" value="" />
</bean>
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInboundAdapter"
    session-factory="ftpClientFactory" channel="ftpChannel"
    filter="ftpPersistantFilter"
    local-filter="fileSystemPersistantFilter" delete-remote-files="false"
    remote-directory="${ftp.remote_directory}/test/" local-directory="${ftp.local_directory}/test/"
    temporary-file-suffix=".writing" auto-create-local-directory="true">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" max-messages-per-poll="-1" />
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

The output log of 1st server is:

```
19-Feb-2016 10:34:41.634 INFO [task-scheduler-1] org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.receive Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=/home/harsh/test/test_input_file1.txt, headers={id=1793c207-2d8a-542c-c5a7-eac9165e4cc5, timestamp=1455858281634}]]
19-Feb-2016 10:34:42.886 INFO [task-scheduler-4] org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.receive Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=/home/harsh/test/test_input_file1.txt, headers={id=c909b6cc-9f78-2f6f-2a27-036f0186b959, timestamp=1455858282886}]]
File /home/harsh/test/test_input_file1.txt transformed by 1st war 1793c207-2d8a-542c-c5a7-eac9165e4cc5
File /home/harsh/test/test_input_file1.txt transformed by 1st war c909b6cc-9f78-2f6f-2a27-036f0186b959
19-Feb-2016 10:34:47.892 INFO [task-scheduler-4] org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.receive Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=/home/harsh/test/test_input_file1.txt, headers={id=8c5c8941-fbfd-91d8-9a25-75d46e450930, timestamp=1455858287892}]]
19-Feb-2016 10:34:49.325 INFO [task-scheduler-2] org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.receive Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=/home/harsh/test/test_input_file1.txt, headers={id=dbdddd0f-1ac5-0753-8873-f0f9c77cb48b, timestamp=1455858289325}]]
Service Activator /home/harsh/test/test_input_file1.txt 1st war 24632436-d297-db0c-c9ea-ac596c57a91e
19-Feb-2016 10:34:50.372 INFO [task-scheduler-2] org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.receive Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=/home/harsh/test/test_input_file1.txt, headers={id=5cc843ae-c1d7-814f-b9fd-a7c5c2515674, timestamp=1455858290372}]]
19-Feb-2016 10:34:51.759 INFO [task-scheduler-2] org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.receive Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=/home/harsh/test/test_input_file1.txt, headers={id=428ba015-e2f3-6948-fc13-ca0df31ee9c0, timestamp=1455858291759}]]
19-Feb-2016 10:34:53.670 INFO [task-scheduler-2] org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.receive Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=/home/harsh/test/test_input_file1.txt, headers={id=ac1fca37-838f-39fc-f9ed-cc373f8f8b12, timestamp=1455858293670}]]
19-Feb-2016 10:34:55.648 INFO [task-scheduler-8] org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.receive Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=/home/harsh/test/test_input_file1.txt, headers={id=f9197ec2-e73a-19be-e94b-94bffe515569, timestamp=1455858295647}]]
File /home/harsh/test/test_input_file1.txt transformed by 1st war 45718961-2a99-d368-d88a-9bc2ceb955cd
```

The 2nd server is generating the same log with different message ids.
Am I missing something in this?
Do I need to write my custom filter for this??

Comment: Any update on this, please????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is, will it able to handle around 5 millions files per day?

That depends on the size of the files and the bandwidth of the network; the use of Spring Integration is unlikely to be a factor.

You should probably remove files locally after processing, though, to avoid large directory scans.

To avoid duplicates in a cluster, you need to use a `FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` backed by a shared metadata store so that each instance will skip files handled by other instances.

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-inbound) for more information.

**EDIT**:

I just tested with your configuration and see no problems. Are you sure both instances are using the same Redis server?

If you run `redis-cli` and then `monitor`, you should see something like:

```
1459258131.934949 [0 127.0.0.1:55237] "HSETNX" "MetaData" "bar.txt" "1384837200000"
1459258131.935129 [0 127.0.0.1:55237] "HSETNX" "MetaData" "baz.txt" "1384837200000"
1459258131.940125 [0 127.0.0.1:55237] "HSETNX" "MetaData" "/tmp/test/bar.txt" "1459258131000"
1459258131.940353 [0 127.0.0.1:55237] "HSETNX" "MetaData" "/tmp/test/baz.txt" "1459258131000"
```

In this case, the remote directory had 2 files; the first 2 lines are from the remote filter, the last two are from the local filter (setting the initial values).

You should then see a bunch of

```
1459258142.073316 [0 127.0.0.1:55237] "HSETNX" "MetaData" "bar.txt" "1384837200000"
1459258142.073506 [0 127.0.0.1:55237] "HGET" "MetaData" "bar.txt"
```

(once per poll - checking to see if the timestamp changed).

Comment: But suppose, there are 10 files on my FTP server and I started my `Inbound Adapter`, then it stored metadata into the `Metadata Store` for all files and then it started transferring the files from FTP to local file system. After transferring 5 files I restarted my server, then adapter didn't transfer remaining 5 files. What should we do in this case?

Comment: If there is an exception while file 6 is being copied, files 6-10 will be removed from the metadata store. If you simply kill the server while the files are being copied, the files will remain in the store and you'll have to clean them up manually. Since file systems are not transactional (generally), there's not much else that can be done.

Comment: I have set up the `FTP Inbound Adapter` on 2 different servers and both servers are configured to use shared `Redis Metadata Store`. When I started both the servers, both the servers started transferring all the files. After that, both servers generated messages from those files multiple times with multiple message ids. I am useing `FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` and `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`

Comment: You need to show your configuration and DEBUG logs. Edit the question don't try to put it in a comment.