# Spring SFTP read file lock

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I have configured Spring integration SFTP application to poll file from remote server, and it's working fine if it's running one, where if the same application run's 3 time, to process the files faster, in such case same file is polled by two application's and resulting in duplicate results. how can i avoid this? is there any file locking available in Spring integration?

for configuration part you can look through this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247467/1066779)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use persistent file list filters together with a shared metadata store - e.g. Redis [see the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-inbound).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34461129/spring-integration-ftp-inbound-adapter-in-distributed-mode) has a similar setup for FTP.